# Installing/Running Spork-Rails on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spork

After installing spork-rails I get this error when running 'spork':

```
Andrews-Mac-Pro-4:lb_final chapmanf16$ spork
/Users/chapmanf16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/spork:23:in load': cannot load such file -      - /Users/chapmanf16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/bin/spork (LoadError)
from /Users/chapmanf16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/spork:23:in'
from /Users/chapmanf16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in eval'
from /Users/chapmanf16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in'
```

If I run 'sudo spork' none of my gems are being located. I will get the following errors:

```
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Could not find actionpack-4.0.0 in any of the sources
```

It literally can't find any gems because if I list the versions of the gem being mentioned and install only the version it is asking for, it will tell me the next gem is not install. I'm just trying to figure out why the path to my gemfile is not being recognized by spark. I have only started learning ruby/rails for the past 3 days so I'm completely out of my element, but I am really not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

I also posted this question I have on spark-rails github -https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails/issues/20

Comment: SPORK 1.0.0rc3 has wrong permissions and must be corrected. This worked for me: sudo chmod -R a+r /Users/chapmanf16/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3

Answer (score 1):

spork-rails from RubyGems doesn't support Rails 4. Try to update you Gemfile with a github reference for the spork:

```
gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
```

and run `bundle update`